# How to generate dynamic name and id for a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript function which is used to generate textfield dynamically, when clicking the previous textfield.

#### HTML

```
<input class="incfield" type="text" name="textfield" />
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () {
var createNewField = function () {
    var $node = $('<input class="incfield" type="text" name="textfield");

    $node.one('click', createNewField);
    $(this).after($node);

}
    };

$('input.incfield').one('click', createNewField);
```

});

The function is working properly but I want that the textfield should have an `id` and `name` tag, dynamically generated.

For example: for the first textfield id=t1 t2,...etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $(function () {
    var cnt= 0;
    var createNewField = function () {
    var $node = $('<input class="incfield'+cnt+'" type="text" name="textfield'+cnt+'"/>');

        $node.one('click', createNewField);
        $(this).after($node);
    cnt++;
    }
 };
```

This will create a dynamic name and id "incfield0" and "textfield0"

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
$(function () {
  var createNewField = function () {
      var $node = $('<input class="incfield" type="text" name="textfield">');

      var n = $('input.incfield').length;

      $node[0].id = "t" + n;
      $node[0].name = "t" + n;

      $node.one('click', createNewField);
      $(this).after($node);

  }

  $('input.incfield').one('click', createNewField);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var createNewField = function () {
 var n = $("input.incfield:text").length+1;
    var $node = $('<input class="incfield" id='+n+' type="text" name="textfield">');

    $node.one('click', createNewField);
    $(this).after($node);

}
```